# Facebook publish to stream and attach link

Tags: facebook

I'm currently using the [Facebook Developer Toolkit](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/) to publish to my organization's Facebook page. I'd like to be able to attach a link, but can't quite seem to figure out the syntax.  Here's what I'm trying.

```
ConnectSession fbSession = new ConnectSession(API_KEY, API_SECRET);
Api fbApi = new Api(fbSession);
attachment attach = new attachment();
attach.href = "http://www.google.com";
attach.caption = "Google";
attach.name = "Google";
String post = "Here's a cool new search engine I found!";
fbApi.Stream.Publish(post, attach, null, null, Convert.ToInt64(fanPageId));
```

Here's what I'm going for:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use that the Facebook Developer Toolkit because it's not being properly supported (personal opinion :P) use the [FacebookC#SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)
2. What you want to post are referred to as 'action_links' and can only be posted using the OLD REST API, not the new graph api (https://api.facebook.com/method/stream.publish)
3. In order to post it you need to encode the JSON in the form:

   action_links: [
               { text: "TITLE", href: "LINK"}
           ]

Comment: I will give the Facebook C# SDK a shot. Thanks for the tip. I've tried using Action Links before and what I get is an additional link in the row at the bottom (i.e. "Comment", "Like", "Share", "Promote", "MyLink").

Comment: for any interested, the FacebookC#SDK which uses the updated Facebook Graph API makes this very easy.